# The Yoneda product for degree 0

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Both in the Wikipeda page and in several other sources I have seen something like the following:

Consider $\mathrm{Ext}^n(A,B)$ as the group (assuming there are enough injectives/projectives) of long exact sequences
$$
0 \to B \to T_1 \to \ldots \to T_n \to A \to 0
$$
up to a certain equivalence relation. With this definition one can define a Yoneda product
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(A,B) \otimes \mathrm{Ext}^n(B,C) \stackrel{\phi_n}{\to} \mathrm{Ext}^n(A,C)
$$
by "functoriality of maps", but I am not sure about what this means exactly, and since there is no place where I can verify it I wanted to ask here.

I'm going to stick to the case $n =1$. The way I would define it is the following:
Given an element
$$
\alpha = [0 \to C \stackrel{g}{\to} T \stackrel{h}{\to} B \to 0] \in \mathrm{Ext}^1(B,C)
$$
and $\beta = [A \stackrel{f}{\to} B] \in \mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$, define
$$
\phi_1(\alpha \otimes\beta) = [0 \to C \to T' \to A \to 0] \in \mathrm{Ext}(A,C)
$$
where $T'$ is the fibered product of $f$ and $h$, and the map $C \to T'$ is induced from the morphisms $g$ and $C \stackrel{0}{\to} A$.

Q1: Is this the correct definition?

Q2: For an arbitrary $n$ one just does iterated fibered products?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for the answer. About projectives and injectives, one needs to put some condition otherside $\mathrm{Ext}$ could be a proper class.